# length of substring in string compare

Tags: c++, string

```
int compare (size_t pos, size_t len, const string& str,
         size_t subpos, size_t sublen) const;
```

in this function,why the length of substring sublen is required ? When we want to compare the two strings, this length should be anyway equal to len .

Comment: Are you sure, you don't intend to look at `int compare (const string& str) const;` instead? You can look at the overloaded methods http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

Comment: If you don't want to compare with the context of substring.. you may use strmcp() function which will take only two strings https://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/standard_library_functions/string_h/strcmp.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe only strings of the same length can be equal, but not only strings of the same length can be compared.

And remember `compare` can also return whether a string is "greater than" or "less than" another string, using the sign of the return value, if they are not equal.

Answer (score 1):

This might be required if you want to compare 2 substrings of 2 different strings.

It is explained very well here : [std::compare function - C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/)

The concept is, you may have 2 strings and want to compare only parts of them. Something like 2nd to 5th characters of one string to 3rd to the 6th character of another. This function does not take in end point. So your input will be only 2 and 3 for each string respectively. Now for it to figure how far to compare you need to give the length.

Basically for specifying what substrings of 2 strings you wish to compare.